# How can I generate a XSD with an xs:element which is optional using JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb, schema

My model object look something like this:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "appConfig")
@XmlType(propOrder = {})
public class Config implements Serializable {
...
private int advancedFooBar;
...
@XmlElement(name = "advancedfoobar")
public int getAdvancedFooBar() {
    return advancedFooBar;
}

public void setAdvancedFooBar(int advancedFooBar) {
    this.advancedFooBar = advancedFooBar ;
}
```

When I generate a schema against this class w/JXC I end up with the following for the above property:

```xml
<xs:element name="advancedfoobar" type="xs:int"/>
```

I'd like this to be an optional element so I tried changing

```java
@XmlElement(name = "advancedfoobar")
```

to

```java
@XmlElement(name = "advancedfoobar", required=false)
```

However, that did not result any change to the generated schema.  What do I need to do so that the "advancedfoobar" element will be defined as optional in the generated schema?

I am using JDK 1.7.0_U3 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Thanks.

-Noah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**WHAT THE JAVADOCS SAY**

According to the Javadoc for `@XmlElement` (see:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#required%28%29)

> If required() is false, then the Javabean property is mapped to XML
>   Schema element declaration with minOccurs="0". maxOccurs is "1" for a
>   single valued property and "unbounded" for a multivalued property.

The schema definition for `advancedfoobar` should be `minOccurs=0` for the following mappings:

```
@XmlElement(name = "advancedfoobar")
public int getAdvancedFooBar() {
    return advancedFooBar;
}
```

and

```
@XmlElement(name = "advancedfoobar", required=false)
public int getAdvancedFooBar() {
    return advancedFooBar;
}
```

---

**BUG IN MOXy AND REFERENCE IMPLEMENTATION**

There appears to be a bug in both [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) and the JAXB reference implementation regarding primitives and optional elements.  I have opened the following bug against MOXy.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/395301

---

**WORKAROUND**

You can make the property of type `Integer` instead of `int`.  Or better yet just set the `type` property on the `@XmlElement` annotation to be `Integer`.  Any type capable of holding a `null` value will be optional by default.

**Config**

```
package forum13595629;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "appConfig")
@XmlType(propOrder = {})
public class Config implements Serializable {

    private int advancedFooBar;

    @XmlElement(name = "advancedfoobar", type=Integer.class)
    public int getAdvancedFooBar() {
        return advancedFooBar;
    }

    public void setAdvancedFooBar(int advancedFooBar) {
        this.advancedFooBar = advancedFooBar;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum13595629;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.SchemaOutputResolver;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Config.class);

        jc.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {

            @Override
            public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri,
                    String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                result.setSystemId(suggestedFileName);
                return result;
            }

        });

    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xsd:complexType name="config">
      <xsd:all>
         <xsd:element name="advancedfoobar" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xsd:all>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="appConfig" type="config"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: @Blaze: OK I'll try that. I'd noticed that String types which I had seemed to automatically be optional and I was wondering what was special about int. It seems odd to me that schema gen doesn't use @XMLElement(required) to figure this out for primitives.

Comment: @NBW - This seems to be a bug.  I've updated my answer with additional info.  I lead the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) implementation and I've filed a bug for this issue.  This also appears to be in issue in the JAXB RI and I would suggest you enter a bug against that impl as well:  http://jaxb.java.net

Comment: @NBW Thanks Blaze, I followed your earlier suggestion and that worked. I may, or may not try the new one (time permitting) but conceptually that makes sense as a work around as well.